# wget with acceptance test, redirect fails the test

Tags: wget, recursive

I'm running the command:

```
wget -r --wait=2 --random-wait -P ./pdfs -A pdf -e robots=off https://www.<somesite>/documents
```

The command has worked on other sites to recursively download all pdfs, but on the site I need it is not fetching anything. The detailed error log points out where it's breaking. It gets a redirect to /document/latest and then breaks:

```
Deciding whether to enqueue "https://www.<somesite>/document/latest"
https://www.<somesite>/document/latest (latest) does not match acc/rej rules.
Decided NOT to load it.
```

I'm not sure whether it's breaking due to a security redirect or because it thinks /latest is a file due to no trailing backslash. What I have tried so far is just stripping down as many options as I can, and adding in the ignoring of robots. I can't remove -A pdf because then I'm just going to be overloaded with junk. What is wrong here and how do I fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd look at using CURL or even telnet to connect and see what headers, etc are being sent.  Also maybe start the wget pointing at /latest and see if it continues down into it, if /latest is a directory then specifying an index page or adding a / may do it.  If /latest is simply a pointer to a pdf file it may be rejecting it because it doesn't end in pdf and it can't get a directory listing of its contents, so it isn't a directory to descend into.

Comment: Okay thanks. I kept digging around with curl etc and yea it was just rejecting the links onto the pages that housed the pdfs because it thought that those links were files that didn't match the acceptance rule. So what I've done now is used regexes to get all the links to pages which will have pdfs on them, and then run wget separately on each of *those* pages. This has worked.